# How to contact the Moroccan consulate in Frankfurt regarding a travel visa?

Tags: visas, international-travel, morocco, consulates

I live in Bavaria, Germany and I need to apply to the consulate of Morocco in Frankfurt for a travel visa.

The procedure of applying for a travel visa is to send an application first (without the original passport) and upon approval of the visa, you have to go personally to collect the visa.

I have been trying to reach the consulate of Morocco in Frankfurt for the last 4 days continuously but nobody picks up the call, nobody answers emails. Does anybody else experienced the same thing and how did you finally contact them?

Comment: Facing the same trouble! Can you please share what did you do?

Comment: I had to do make several calls from Berlin to Munich and finally, I got the number of the concerned person.  The lady at this number (+49 69 949459140) receives the call if you call 2-5 times. Since I have several numbers of Moroccan consulate accumulated in my mobile, I am not sure if this is the correct number.

Answer (score 1):

The [Consulate of Morocco Frankfurt](http://www.consulat.ma/fr/consulat.cfm?post=18)

> Ostparkstraße 35 60385 FRANKFURT/AM MAIN
>
> Tél : 00 (49) 69 94 94 59 100
>   Fax : 00 (49) 69 94 94 59 110
>   E-mail : cgm.frankfurt@maec.gov.ma

As you note, you made successful contact with consulate staff at (49) 69 94 94 59 140